# Filter Table View with buttons iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have two different view controllers containing one table view each, which parses JSON and displays data in the table. 
What I want is two buttons where I can filter the two different table views. If I click for example Button 1, I want the table view to load view the table view from view controller 1. 
If you don't understand what I mean you can check out this app screenshot[image]:

That's exactly how I want it.

Comment: you mean..you want a button strip at the top and below that u'll show tableView ?

Comment: I have recently done exactly same thing in my app but using two UIView not ViewControllers. About Json parser i have separate parser class which pass data to view controller and then VC pass that data to corresponding Views.

Comment: @BishalGhimire : yup..that would be a good option to use two views instead of viewControllers, and would be easy to integrate everything in this way...only thing need to take care is handling datasource and delegate methods of tableView for two tables by putting proper conditions..